# Count of insert and update by an employee

Tags: sql-server

i/p

```
Id Name   InsertBy UpdateBy
1  A       2         2
2  B       1         2
3  C       4         3
4  D       4         5 
5  E       1         3
```

O/P(THE COUNT OF EMPLOYEE ID IN INSERT AND COUNT OF EMPID IN UPDATE)

```
Name InsertBy  UpdateBy  
 A       2         0
 B       1         2
 C       0         2
 D       2         0 
 E       0         1
```

Comment: what is your requirement for the above tables

Comment: If you don't post the question in the meaningful manner such that the users should able to understand .otherwise you will deserve more and more down votes . FYI refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Before posting a question

Comment: I have mentioned input and output.. what shall i mwention more.. if anyone dont understand they can ask @Mahesh.K

Comment: You better post what you have tried so far and your piece of sample code the way you posted the question is not quite good . your question looking us like as an order/demand instead of a concern or request . SO users won't help people who demand for an answer .

Comment: i AM NOT GETTING IDEA what to write thats why asking.. i

Answer (score 1):

It seems to you would require to do self join with separate query (`Inserted, Updated`) for safer.

```
SELECT 
       t.name, a.insertBy, b.updateBy 
FROM table t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
           t.id, count (t1.insertBy) insertBy
    FROM table t
    LEFT JOIN table t1 on t1.insertBy = t.id
    GROUP BY t.id
)a on a.id = t.id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
           t.id, count (t2.updateBy) updateBy
    FROM table t
    LEFT JOIN table t2 on t2.updateBy = t.id
    GROUP BY t.id

)b on b.id = t.id
```

Let me edit with other approach which more efficient with separate `join`

```
select t1.name, sum(case when a.Name = 'InsertedBy' then 1 else 0 end) InsertBy,
                sum(case when a.Name = 'UpdatedBy' then 1 else 0 end) UpdateBy    
from table t
cross apply (
    values (InsertBy, 'InsertedBy'), (UpdateBy, 'UpdatedBy')
)a(Types, Name)
LEFT JOIN table t1 on t1.Id = a.Types
group by t1.name
```

However, these will make use of index on (`Id`)

Comment: Hi Yogesh,the query seems correct but is it not possible with a small query?

Comment: @AryanDas.. This would be in safe side with separate query to produce consistence  counts.